# File access in android 11 gives exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android

I am not able to send selected file to server using multipart in android 11, I am able to send till android 10 but on android 11 it gives exception

targetSdkVersion: 29

requestLegacyExternalStorage=true in Manifest.xml

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/dir/file.txt : open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: on a real device or emulator from Android Studio?  I'd try both.  Was the file created by the app trying to gain access to it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: `/storage/dir/file.txt` That is an impossible path. No wonder it fails.

Comment: Yes, app created that file using File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images/new.jpg") and when try to access to that it gives this exception